# RequestDispatcher.forward loop

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am  using

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

to map all the requests to one sevlet,where i do all the authentication work.
but I want to skip some static content (like css files).so I tried fowrding them from
that sevlet to where the resource file is

```
if(isResourceFile){
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("static/" + fileName);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

but this will start a infinite loop because this will again call the same sevlet

is there any way to work around this without mapping all the resource(css) files in web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're looking to authenticate just JSP files, you could change the URL:

```
/*.jsp
```

I think it's a better idea to handle your authentication using a filter rather than a servlet. And in a production environment, you should use a front-end webserver for static content.

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly.I am planing not to use .jsp suffix in URLs.I'll try to use a filter.

Comment: Please user / as the url-mapping in your frontcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

The `url-pattern` of `/*`  is better to be used exclusively by `Filter`s, not `Servlet`s. Put all your static files in a certain folder (maybe covered by the `url-pattern` of a more effective [FileServlet](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)?) and let the Filter check it.

E.g. (pseudo)

```
public void doFilter(request, response, chain) {
    if (requestURI.startsWith("/static")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue. Do nothing.
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages").forward(request, response); // Forward to page controller.
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot use a filter and you have to use a wildcard '*' in the mapping without a extension like '.jsp' then then this  could work for you:

```
if(isResourceFile){
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/static/" + fileName);
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      return; 
}
```

Adding the '/' in the beginning of the static directory will give it root context.