# Tiles 2 And No mapping found for HTTP request with URI - Spring-MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mapping, tiles, tiles2

I want to use Spring-Tiles intergration. [Here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=90431) you can see how my app looks like.

So my question is: why Spring-MVC dispatcher Servlet can not resolve my Target page ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in servlet mapping, so all requests are processed by `DispatcherServlet`, including request to `*.jsp` tiles. The most versatile way to solve it (but to keep restful urls without prefixes) is to [use a UrlRewriteFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946995/java-jsp-servlet-controller-servlet-throwing-the-famous-stack-overflow/2949077#2949077).

Comment: @Arthur: All request to Spring MVC controllers are going throgh the DispatcherServlet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a critical ViewResolver. I checked the post you mentioned in SpringSource but I didn't see the following ViewResolver:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver
```

Try adding that ViewResolver and see if that would help. I use Spring and Tiles as well. I just have to declare that and the TilesConfigurer.

Check out these references:

- [Add TilesViewResolver to enable fallback if tiles definition does not exist](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5689)
- [TilesViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesViewResolver.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's a common issue using Spring and it's due to the fact that the view (jsp) goes through the DispatcherServlet.

Try to modify your web.xml using

```
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
     <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

and then add to your urlrewrite.xml something like:

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
<rule>
    <from>/</from>
    <to>/app/</to>
</rule>
<rule>
    <from>/**</from>
    <to>/app/$1</to>
</rule>
<outbound-rule>
    <from>/app/**</from>
    <to>/$1</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

I'm assuming you're using urlrewrite, if you're not import the jar and add the filter mapping in your web.xml such as:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```