# Spring MVC and Apache Tiles: an 404 issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, tiles2

Good Time.

I'm trying to integrate the Spring MVC and Apache Tiles. The problem is^ when I hit the url I need, the "404 Not Found" raises. Here are my settings:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Administration Panel</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="layout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="layout.header"/>
    <put-attribute name="navigator" value="layout.navigator"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="layout.footer"/>
</definition>

<!-- The header template -->
<definition name="layout.header" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/header.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header.left" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/header/layout_header_left.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="header.center" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/header/layout_header_center.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="header.right" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/header/layout_header_right.jsp"/>
</definition>

<!-- The navigator template -->
<definition name="layout.navigator" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/navigator.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="navigator.top" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/navigator/layout_navigator_top.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="navigator.bottom" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/navigator/layout_navigator_bottom.jsp"/>
</definition>

<!-- The footer template -->
<definition name="layout.footer" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/footer.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="footer.left" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/footer/layout_footer_left.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer.center" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/footer/layout_footer_center.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer.right" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/footer/layout_footer_right.jsp"/>
</definition>
<definition name="blank" extends="layout">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/themes/basic/body/layout_body.jsp"/>
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/base_page")

public class BasePageController {

@RequestMapping("/blank")
public ModelAndView getBasePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("blank");
    return  modelAndView;
}

  }
```

The requested url is: `http://localhost:8080/base_page/blank` (tomcat 7)

Can anybody suggest the solution?

Comment: Do you have your app in ROOT context?

Comment: I test this from an IntelliJIdea 11.1.2 and the artifact's context is always '/'.

Comment: Ok, did you try turning debug on (`log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG`)? Can you post debug output here?

Comment: Ok, I'll try, but I use the logback =)

Comment: Hmm, it says: BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]. But I've specified the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: And also: "GET /base_page/blank HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: So I'd say 404 is just consequence of previos errors - seems that applicationContext.xml is the root of this problem. Is it in /WEB-INF/? Is it valid XML?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977446/tiles-2-and-no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-spring-mvc

Comment: I've added the applicationContext.xml and moved all bean definitions into it (but haven't deleted the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml). Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Xaerxess and axtavt!

The problem is solved, as axtavt pointed, by changing `/*` to `/admin/*`.

Now the question is why Spring is looking for the applicationContext.xml when the xxx-servlet.xml is already here? And what type of beans are required to be placed in the applicationContext.xml (not in other spring configuration files)?