# Spring MVC controller request url mapping

Tags: java, spring, controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tiles 2 And No mapping found for HTTP request with URI - Spring-MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977446/tiles-2-and-no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-spring-mvc)

I can't understand what is wrong with my code. Could you please help me. 
Here the code:

springapp-servlet.xml contains:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

Controller class:

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/views")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewEvents() {
        Map model = new HashMap();
        model.put("result", "TestResult");
        return new ModelAndView ("page1", model);
    }
}
```

I thought that when I open url localhost:8080/myapp/views/index.jsp
the controller must dispatch this request and redirect me to page1, where variable result will be available. But instead I get warning in my jBoss console and nothig happens:

```
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jammies-1.0/WEB-INF/views/views/page1.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp'
```

Whats wrong with my code and config file?
Thanks in advance)

Comment: do you have the file /jammies-1.0/WEB-INF/views/views/page1.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

As kent mentioned, do u have page1.jsp under views/views folder?. You may have the page1.jsp in the views not in the views/views

Comment: Yes, sorry, the warning message is: WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jammies-1.0/WEB-INF/views/page1.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp'

Comment: And I have page1.jsp in views folder

Comment: The problem solved. Thanks to everybody!