# differenct between / and /* in servlet url match pattern

Tags: servlets, url-pattern

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Servlet mapping / vs /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/servlet-mapping-vs)

What is the difference of '/' and '/*' in servlet url mapping?

Since I am reading the book spring in action,and I found these words:

> Next we must indicate what URLs will be handled by the
>   DispatcherServlet. It’s common to find DispatcherServlet mapped to URL
>   patterns such as *.htm, /*, or /app. But these URL patterns have a few
>   problems:
>
> - The  *.htm pattern implies that the response will always be in  HTML    form (which, as we’ll learn in chapter 11, isn’t necessarily
>     the    case).
> - Mapping it to /* doesn’t imply any specify type of response, but    indicates that DispatcherServlet will serve  all requests. That makes 
>     serving static content such as images and stylesheets more difficult than necessary.
> - The  /app pattern (or something similar) helps us distinguish     Dispatcher-Servlet-served content from other types of content. But then we have an implementation detail (specifically, the /app path) exposed in our URLs. That leads to complicated URL rewriting tactics to hide the /app path.
>
> Rather than use any of those flawed servlet-mapping schemes, I prefer
>   mapping DispatcherServlet like this:
>
> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>   <servlet-name>spitter</servlet-name>
>   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```
>
> By mapping DispatcherServlet to /, I’m saying that it’s the default
>   servlet and that it’ll be responsible for handling all requests,
>   including requests for static content.

According the above words, it seems that both '/' and '/*' will server all the request.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

A string containing only the / character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
&

A string beginning with a *. prefix is used as an extension mapping.

> The pattern /* will force everything through your Servlet.
>
> The pattern / will make your Servlet the default Servlet for the app,
>   means that it will pick up every pattern that doesn't have another exact
>   match.

Comment: What is the exactly difference between the default servlet(`/`) and the everything `/*`?