# Catch-all (wildcard) servlet url-pattern overrides file extension patterns

Tags: servlets, web.xml, zk, url-pattern

I would like to achieve the following:

> ```
> /webapp-context/Page-1               -> Handled by my custom "ContentServlet"
> /webapp-context/Another-Page         -> Handled by my custom "ContentServlet"
> /webapp-context/Page-with-long-title -> Handled by my custom "ContentServlet"
>
> /webapp-context/_cms/<something>.zul -> Handled by ZK framework
> ```

My latest attempt looks like this (web.xml extract):

> ```
>   <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
>
>   <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>myContentServlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> ```

Unfortunately now my content servlet handles all requests (I thought the more specific pattern takes precedence?).

No conflict exists if i map my content servlet to the pattern "/webapp-context/content/*", but that's not what I want.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found a solution through this question: [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/servlet-mapping-vs)

Using '/' instead of '/*' did the trick for me.

> ```
> <servlet-mapping>
>   <servlet-name>myContentServlet</servlet-name>
>   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```