# <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> for use by filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

**Objective**

My goal is to get a servlet filter to process requests to the home page before forwarding them to index.jsp.

**Problem**

I'm having trouble getting my filter to receive requests from "/". It's URL pattern is

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Instead requests to that pattern end up directed straight to *index.jsp*.

I read a previous post
[Servlet Mapping / and /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/servlet-mapping-vs) and wonder if mapping to "/" only works if there is no index.jsp in the application folder?

Comment: What is so unclear about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to redirect the user to a servlet before going to the index.jsp page. I would suggest modifying `<welcome-file/>` in `web.xml`.

```
<welcome-file-list>  
<welcome-file>first</welcome-file>  // remember no leading slash
</welcome-file-list>  

<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>firstServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>business.firstServlet</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>firstServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/first</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will make sure that your control goes to first servlet before going to the home page

Comment: Wow. Why didn't I think of that. I'll try this in the morning and come back with the results.