# Redirecting to Spring Servlet for all requests

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a spring application which runs on Tomcat server.  Now my requirement is that all the requests should redirect to app-servlet.xml.

I have configured it as follows:

```
<servlet>    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param><param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

The application is getting started, but the pages are not properly loaded.  Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: Does this question: ["Servlet mapping / vs /*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/servlet-mapping-vs) answer your question?

Comment: @kong.. Yes please.. In our application it is configured as *.htm in the servlet mapping so that only the request whcih ends with .htm will be forwared to app-servlet.Now we need to forward all the requests apart from *.htm.For that purpose i have given url pattern as /.. But now application is not loading properly. i mean functioanlity is working but ui is inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

Doing so, All the requests for static contents (Images and css files) are also being forwarded to your `DispatcherServlet`.

From **Spring 3.0.x**, There is a mechanism to serve static resources through `DispatcherServlet`, what you need is to add the following line in your app-servlet.xml.

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Then you can use the image or css of your resource folder using url like below in jsp pages:

```
  <c:url value="/resources/image/someImage.jpg" />
```

For details:

- [Spring MVC Staic Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources)

Edit:

But for lower versions of Spring there is no shortcut or simple solution to do that. More convenient way is to use specific url pattern for your `DispatcherServlet`, so that the public static resources can be accessed directly and have no mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are using Spring 2.5 in our application

Comment: @Rahaman May i know how to map invalid URL pattern..My Requirement is "For an invalid request i should get 404 error page" But in my application we have pre compiled jsps and i used  <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/WEB-INF/classes/org/pache/jsp/jsp/error/error_jsp</location>
 </error-page>  which is not working for an invalid request.

Comment: What is the problem exactly you are facing?

Comment: @Rahman our app is configured as <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping> so that for all the requests ends with *.htm will be forwared to app-servlet.xml. But if we change the url in the browser something like this - abc.def we should see custom 404 error page.Unable to configure the same way as mentioned above