# Spring: servlet-mapping -> url-pattern : /* working but can't display

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ( "/" )
public class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    @RequestMapping ( "/" )
    public String index ( Model model ){
        System.out.println("AA");
        return index2(model);
    }

    @RequestMapping ( "/index" )
    public String index2 ( Model model ){
        System.out.println("BB");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And exist index.jsp File

[image]

I guess that is very good working

**BBBBBBBBBBBUUUUUUUUUTTTTTTTTT, BUT!**

[image]

WHY????
WHY????
WHY????
WHY????

And More strange

[image]

**??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????**

Controller work it!! but don't display browser

What's going on?

Please help me.

---

And Log

DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp]

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: You should enable Spring logging, you should notice it log that it can't find a handler for `/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`.

Comment: look at log. definitely must try to find the [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp]. 

DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp]
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Comment: Now consider what `/*` means.

Comment: use servlet path  "/", "/series/{id}", "/episode/{id}", "/user/{id}", but i don't want use multi servlet mapping. should never use only one Servlet mapping?

Comment: so i'm find looking exclude resource path

Comment: Following link is also useful for this query : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern/4140659#4140659

Answer (score 12):

Servlet containers have rules for how they map and handle URI requests. These can be found in the [Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html). It's also important to note that most Servlet containers have a `Servlet` to handle JSPs, mapped to `*.jsp`, which is an extension mapping. Tomcat has a `JspServlet` to do this.

You've mapped your `DispatcherServlet` to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

which is a path mapping. Path mappings take precedence over extension mappings. So when you submit your view name

```
return "index";
```

Spring will use the `ViewResolver`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

to resolve a path to use with a `RequestDispatcher`'s `forward` method. That path will be `/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`. Now the Servlet container will receive that path and attempt to find a `Servlet` to handle it. Since you have a `Servlet` mapped to `/*` it will use it, but your `DispatcherServlet` doesn't have a mapping for that path and therefore responds with a 404.

The simple solution is to change your mapping to `/`, which is the default handler if no other matches are found. In this case, when you submit your view and the container must find a mapped `Servlet`, it will find the `JspServlet` and use it.

Comment: he is also mapping /index with "index" which is legal but strange