# Custom jsp tag is not invoked

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to write custom jsp tag. But my tag is not invoked. Instead I got response in plain text with my html and jsp tags(maybe browser doesn't parse it as html because of jsp tags). My tld file is in the right place(/WEB-INF/custom.tld) and I have no errors or exceptions in console and I got no clue what is wrong with my tag. Probably it's because of some jsp dependencies or deployment descriptors. I'm using tomcat 7. My code:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**custom.tld**

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>Test</short-name>
    <tag>
        <name>greet</name>
        <tag-class>com.test.tag.HelloTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ex:greet/>
</body>
</html>
```

**Tag**

```
package com.test.tag;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
        getJspContext().getOut().println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

And my response looks exactly like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="/WEB-INF/custom.tld"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ex:greet/>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try changing `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: do you add jstl jar and jstl tag library?

Comment: where u placed ur "custom.tld" file? r u sure that u placed it inside "WEB-INF"?

Comment: @Afsun Khammadli I thought jstl is lib for standard tags which I don't use here.

Comment: @ Arin yes, it's there.

Comment: @Amit.rk3 I changed it and now it works! I don't understand why, but it works. You can add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Also it would be great if you could explain why it works now. Thank you!

Comment: And also thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For servlet url mapping, you have to use `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` instead of `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`, because `/*` overrides the default JspServlet mapping. You can find more details about difference between `/` and `/*` at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)