# Set servlet as default home page in web.xml

Tags: servlets, web.xml, welcome-file

I've a servlet registered in `web.xml` as below.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Manager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Manager</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Manager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RequestManager</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Basically I want to call this servlet as my default home page when I open `http://localhost:8080/appname`. So, I tried registering it as welcome file in same `web.xml` as below:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Manager</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

But, when I run the project, I get an error saying "requested resource not available". However, if I write in the url with my servlet URL pattern, it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Specify an empty string as servlet's URL pattern.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Manager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Manager</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Manager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `<welcome-file>` should represent an URL path, not a servlet name. It'd have worked if you specifed `<welcome-file>RequestManager</welcome-file>`. But this affects all subfolders. Actually, the `<welcome-file>` has an entirely different meaning than "home page file" you've had in mind. It represents the default resource which should be served when **a folder** is been requested.

Comment: this does not work for me ....  currently i am working with servlet version 3.1. It will be great if you provide solution thanks. @BalusC

Comment: It works for me and anyone else in a blank project. It's more likely that you've something else in your project which is colliding with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index.jsp to forward to your servlet.

```
<jsp:forward page="servlet_context">
```

and add index.jsp as welcome file in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

inside servlet class you can forward Control Using :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("forward page URL").forward(req,res);
```

or else if you are using JSP then use

```
<% RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
rd.forward(request, response); %>
```

or

```
<jsp:forward page="relative URL" />
```