# WebServlet maps multiple paths to /

Tags: java, maven, servlets, tomcat7

I am developing a school project where I am using Tomcat7, Thymeleaf and javax.servlet with MAven as package manager.

My file `IndexServlet.java` is called even when I don't call the path

```
package com.barnacle.travel.web;

import com.barnacle.travel.config.TemplateEngineUtil;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext;

@WebServlet("/")
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());

        TemplateEngine engine = TemplateEngineUtil.getTemplateEngine(request.getServletContext());
        WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, request.getServletContext());
        context.setVariable("recipient", name);
        engine.process("index.html", context, response.getWriter());
    }

}
```

The configuration section for the tomcat7 plugin is:

```xml
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <path>/</path>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Every request gets mapped to the the servlet even though I want the index or `/` to be mapped only. What should be changed?

Comment: Maybe you could use BalusC answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020447/set-servlet-as-default-home-page-in-web-xml

Comment: That link I posted, links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248473/change-default-homepage-in-root-path-to-servlet-with-doget   where BalusC  suggested using  @WebServlet("")  Yes, empty String!

Comment: @rickz thanks. will try it out and update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @rickz in comment and from [Change default homepage in root path to servlet with doGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248473/change-default-homepage-in-root-path-to-servlet-with-doget) editing the code annotation to:

```
@WebServlet("")       //empty string
```

solves the issue. This is due to the fact mentioned here [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140659/13163131) regarding the `/` pattern in web servlets.