# How to set servlet-mapping in servlets corectly to get id values in my controller?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using Servlets and JSP.
I am trying to delete some order from my web app.
Servlets version 3.0, servlet container Tomcat v.7.65.

Part of my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.InitController</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OrderController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.taxi.service.controller.OrderController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InitController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OrderController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/createNewOrder</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/deleteOrderFromAdmin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/editOrderFromAdmin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I am trying to delete order and in my jsp i use:

```
<td><a href="<c:url value='/deleteOrderFromAdmin/${order.id}' />">Delete</a></td>
```

But when i am trying to add special mapping /deleteOrderFromAdmin/* , i am getting an error (i know that my InitController creates this issue because it mapped for "/"):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at com.taxi.service.controller.InitController.doGet(InitController.java:33)
```

My InitController must be loaded on startup because it contains many options for my services and so for other web-services from my app.

In my Order delete method i am using some kind of path interpritation like this:

```
 Long orderId = null;
            String[] pathParts = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
            if(pathParts != null && StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(pathParts[1])){
                orderId = Long.parseLong(pathParts[1]);
            }
            if (orderId != null) {
                orderService.deleteOrder(orderId);
            }
```

I must to take this order id and must to delete it.

**Question:** How to solve that problem with mapping?

Thanks.

**Update:**

All those mapping changes ("/*") are starting from my needs to get that order id from my jsp page. Is there some alternative way to made such thing to get those id from jsp?

Comment: show the complete stack trace, and also `doGet` method in InitController

Comment: Wich Servlet version are you using ? You might need to reorder your mappings so that `InitController` is the last if you want your request to go to the right controller. By the way, why do you need the `/*` in your mappings ?

Comment: I am using Servlets 3.0. This mapping "/*" appeared when i were trying to get Order id from my Jsp page by using button with special url: <c:url value='/deleteOrderFromAdmin/${order.id}' />.Unfortunately i didn't know alternative to solve this thing without affecting servlet mapping.

Comment: Mapping application-specific servlets on `/*` or `/` is Bad Practice. The `/*` should be used for filters only and the `/` should be used for global front controller servlets only who are also capable of dealing with static resources. Food for read (and likely also a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/4140448

Comment: Hi BalusC, i read much info from your answers and must to say Thanks for all your work in here.
The reason i asked that question: i am trying to get order id from my jsp page, and i started to make such things with mapping (in Spring i had no problems with it, but in servlets, i need to find some way to get id without mapping changing).