# Error of deployement of a simple War file ( J2EE application ) with Jboss

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss

In a J2EE application I had to do, everything is compiling and the projet.war is created. When I deploy with Jboss ( which is obligatory ), I have the following error:

```
Deploying C:\Users\samyham\Videos\projet\dist\projet.war
{"JBAS014653: Opération composite échouée et annulée. Étapes déficientes :" => {"Opération step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Les services ont échoué" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./projet" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./projet: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Échec du démarrage du contexte
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Échec du démarrage du contexte"}}}}
C:\Users\samyhamidouche\Videos\projet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1035: The module has not been deployed.
```

Here is the log of the server :

```
09:03:03,722 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1093) JBWEB001097: Error starting context /projet: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBWEB000282: Invalid <url-pattern> /*.html in Servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2227) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2203) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.processWebMetaData(JBossContextConfig.java:482) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(JBossContextConfig.java:201) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:354) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:153) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:194) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3717) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

09:03:03,804 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1093) JBWEB001103: Error detected during context /projet start, will stop it
09:03:03,808 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1093) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./projet: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./projet: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Échec du démarrage du contexte
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040: Échec du démarrage du contexte
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:166)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    ... 6 more
JBAS014775: Nouvelles dépendances manquantes/non complétées : 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component.CategorieFacade.START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component.ClientFacade.START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component.Facade.START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component.ReservationFacade.START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."managed-bean.org.apache.struts.faces.util.StrutsContext".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.BaseTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.CommandLinkTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.HtmlTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.JavascriptValidatorTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.LoadMessagesTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.MessageTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.StylesheetTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.faces.taglib.WriteTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.CookieTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.DefineTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.IncludeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.ResourceTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.SizeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.ButtonTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.CancelTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.ErrorsTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FileTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FrameTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.HiddenTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.HtmlTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.ImgTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.JavascriptValidatorTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LinkTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.MessagesTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.MultiboxTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.OptionTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.OptionsTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.PasswordTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.ResetTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.SubmitTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TextareaTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.html.XhtmlTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.EmptyTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.EqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.ForwardTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.GreaterThanTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.IterateTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.LessEqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.LessThanTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.MatchTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.MessagesNotPresentTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.MessagesPresentTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.NotEmptyTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.NotEqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.NotPresentTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.PresentTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.RedirectTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.NestedRootTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.NestedWriteNestingTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.bean.NestedMessageTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.bean.NestedSizeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.bean.NestedWriteTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedCheckboxTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedErrorsTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedFileTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedFormTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedHiddenTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedImageTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedImgTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedMessagesTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedMultiboxTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedOptionsTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedPasswordTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedSelectTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedSubmitTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.html.NestedTextTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedEmptyTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedEqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedGreaterEqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedGreaterThanTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedLessEqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedLessThanTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedMatchTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedMessagesNotPresentTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedNotEqualTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedNotMatchTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.taglib.nested.logic.NestedNotPresentTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.AddTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.DefinitionTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.GetAttributeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.ImportAttributeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InitDefinitionsTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.PutListTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.UseAttributeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.strutsel.taglib.bean.ELIncludeTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.strutsel.taglib.bean.ELMessageTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.strutsel.taglib.bean.ELPageTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
Dépendances service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".component."org.apache.strutsel.taglib.bean.ELResourceTag".START (manquantes) : [service jboss.deployment.unit."projet.war".deploymentCompleteS .........
```

Sorry for the sometimes French words , Jboss is in french , I use NetBeans and Jboss 6.3. How can I correct this?

Comment: Who can tell?  Check your WAR to make sure it's correct.  You probably depend too much on NetBeans and don't know enough about WARs or JBOSS.

Comment: Forcing English error messages might help us understand the problem

Comment: I added some details. please check out the server Log

Answer (score 1):

Have you try replace the url-mapping to another format? Try *.html instead of /*.html

You can see another possible pattern from https://developer.jboss.org/thread/76911?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t

There, if you do it just for mapping the extension, you don't need the / prefix.

Comment: that was the problem , now It deploys , but when I open http://localhost:8080/projet/ , I have the following error message : JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /projet/

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /projet/

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
JBoss Web/7.4.8.Final-redhat-4

Comment: I already answered that the problem is the invalid url-mapping. It's in the log above. So, he just need to remove the / prefix.

Comment: @Sam Ham. Could you provide the complete web.xml?

Comment: @Bogie here is the web.xml : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">

Comment: <servlet>
<servlet-name>Serv</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>servlets.Serv</servlet-class> 
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Serv</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: <welcome-file-list> 
<welcome-file>/WebContent/index.html</welcome-file> 
<welcome-file>/WebContent/Accueil.html</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
   <display-name>tous les jsp </display-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
  </jsp-property-group>
 </jsp-config>
        
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>   
 </session-config>


</web-app>

Comment: You might be interested to read another answered question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern

Comment: Because you have mapped the servlet "Serv" with *.do, all incoming request with ".do" suffix will processed by that servlet class. You can  redirect to any .do sufficed URL from your welcome file. So that any request to your context URL will be redirected and processed by the server.