# How to access .js file from within a servlet which is part of a web application plugin?

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, web-applications

I can't find a way to access a javascript file which I put in the project folder of a plugin which I am trying to extend. The provided solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582025/my-jsp-file-doesnt-find-my-javascript-file) unfortunately didn't work. I hope this is not specific to the webapp (lets say its called `thiswebappname`) I am writing the plugin for.
I started by extending on an existing example plugin, which has following project structure:

## Project structure

myprojectsnamespace.myproject

- JRE System Library
- Plug-in Dependencies
- src

  - myprojectsnamespace.myproject

    - MyServlet.java
    - ...
- META-INF
- webapp

  - WEB-INF

    - javascript

      - myScript.js
  - web.xml
- build.properties
- plugin.xml

here some of the files which I suspect might be helpful for finding a solution:

## build.properties

```
source.my-servlet.jar = src/
src.includes = my-servlet.jar
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               webapp/,\
               plugin.xml
```

## plugin.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.0"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="com.thiswebappname.portal.tomcat.webapps">
      <webapp
            contextRoot="webapp"
            name="thiswebappname/myprojectsnamespace"/>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

I'm somehow not able to load the content of `myScript.js` from `MyServlet`. The servlet is kinda published by the `web.xml`:

```xml
<...>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <display-name>My Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-class>myprojectnamespace.myproject.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LoadScript</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In `MyServlet.java` I tried the following, all without success:

## MyServlet.java

```java
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws IOException{
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.getWriter().println("<script>");
    resp.getWriter().println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("getPopup.js")),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    //above line doesn't find the file. I also tried "myprojectsnamespace.myproject/webapp/WEB-INF/javascript/myScript.js" etc., same problem
    resp.getWriter().println("</script>");

    /* following approach has the same problem, i.e. can't find the file:
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    resp.getWriter().println("<script language='text/javascript' src='myScript.js'>");
    resp.getWriter().println("</script>"); */
}
```

When I enter `http://myserver/thiswebappname/LoadScript` in a browser, `doGet()` does get called from `MyServlet` as expected, but the script doesn't get loaded. Am I missing something obvious? I haven't found a way to "publish" the .js file like I did with MyServlet in the web.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
ServletContext context = getContext();
URL resourceUrl = context.getResource("/WEB-INF/javascript/myScript.js");
```

or alternatively if you just want the input stream:

```
InputStream resourceContent = context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/javascript/myScript.js");
```

This works even if the Servlet Container never expands the WAR file (like Tomcat).

Comment: I ended up using the InputStream variant in a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block, tyvm!

Comment: for future reference: `ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext()` and `String scriptTag = IOUtils.toString(context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/javascript/myScript.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`