# Catch-all servlet and JSP infinite loop

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am experimenting with Servlet+JSP MVC model, but can't understand where I am wrong.

My first try is a "catch-all" @WebServlet which should act as a "router" for all requests:

```
@WebServlet( urlPatterns = {"/*"} )
public class RoutingServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println(req.getPathInfo());      
        req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

This gives me a ***StackOverflowError***.

How can I make the servlet "exclude" .jsp from its catch-all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you don't want /* mappings on a servlet - just a filter.  '/*' pattern is going to send everything to your servlet.  I would suggest you define something like *.html (a logical mapping) as your mapping and then forward to jsps housed inside WEB-INF.

Comment: A great summary of URL pattern use cases:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern