# Why Request doesn't reach to controller in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I try many examples to find out why requests doesn't reach to my controller,but it fails.
when i do start my application it'll show homepage (index.jsp) but when i fill the form and press submit button it gives me 404 not found error!
here is my files :

**Index.jsp (HomePage)**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/form">
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**StudentController.java**

```
package rankbooster.ir.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

/**
  * Created by Mohammad Reza Khatami on 4/23/2016.
*/
@Controller
public class StudentController
{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/form",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String getFormData(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model)
   {
      model.addAttribute("name",name);
      return "index2";
   }
}
```

**index2.jsp**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <b>${name}</b>
    <b>${family}</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee      
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="rankbooster.ir.controller"/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />



    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Is your `index2.jsp` in the `/WEB-INF/pages/` directory?

Comment: yes it is under /WEB-INF/pages/

Comment: What is the URL your application is deployed on

Comment: it's localhost:8080 , the problem is , it seems the request by localhost:8080/form , never called controller to handle

Comment: Post your controller not only the method.

Comment: controller is updated.

Comment: Is your application really deployed as root i.e. `/` or something else?

Comment: what is your mean ?! all of my project files is included. if your mean is my application context in run configuration is "/" . then it is

Comment: Enable debug logging for `org.springframework` and check what is happening. It can be either your controller isn't detected/mapped or the files aren't in the location you say they are (index2.jsp that is).

Comment: i didn't know what i should to do but now i add log4j jar to my project and get logger object from my controller class and put debug & error methods in getFormData method(which should takes care /form request) and add log4j.properties under my web folder (i think it's root path in spring!)

Comment: what i should to do now ?

Comment: It isn't about the logging in the controller it is the logging of the spring framework you should be interested in. That way you can see if your bean is even being picked up or the dispatcherservlet is even handling the request.

Comment: my log4j.properties file is under web folder and contains this lines log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE , log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:\\log.out , log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug , but when i run my app, i cant find log.out file under c drive so how can i see logs ?!

Comment: put the file in the correct location `src/main/resources`.

Comment: src/main/resources/log4j.properties shouldn't be log4j.xml for xml configuration project ?! i can't see log file yet.

Comment: either will work. Have you included the log4j jar? and are you sure the file is in that location and packaged with your app?

Comment: ok, yes it is under src/main/resources and it appends to FileAppender.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form method="post" action="/form">
```

change the above line to this

```
<form method="post" action="form">
```

Comment: it doesn't change.

Comment: bt you have to change that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the servlet mapping for the dispatcher servlet as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(Note the `/*`)

Refer to [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern) for details.

Comment: when i do this, i can't see my homepage because 404 error code (under web folder), and localhost:8080/form gives 404 not found too.

Comment: Ok, then you seem to have an additional problem that I don't see at the moment. Maybe you can increase the log level of the DispatcherServlet to gain more insight?

Comment: in dispatcher-servlet.xml navigates to controller is fine (ctrl + click), also i have applicationContext.xml which is empty.