# Path mapping for servlet deployed to Wildfly 10

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0, wildfly-10

I made my first attempt to create a servlet and in result there is a problem I cannot solve ;(

My entry page, simple hello world, looks this way:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class EntryServlet extends HttpServlet {


   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
       resp.setContentType("text/html");

       PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
       writer.println("Hello World");
       writer.close();
   }
```

So my expectation to @WebServlet("/") is that GET / returns Hello World page.
All other requests, ex GET /wrong-url should return 404. Surprisingly, after deploying WAR to Wildfly10, I received "Hello World" for each url I tried.

So @WebServlet("/") behaves as kinda @WebServlet("/*") - is it as it should be or am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE
I found the answer here:
[Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I think use  @WebServlet("/helloworld") instead of @WebServlet("/") . so that if you put GET /wrong-url  it will give 404 error.