# Servlet URL Mappings: View Resolver causing StackOverflow

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Using websphere app server.
Web.xml has the mappings:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myconfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSPDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.dispatcher.JSPDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSPDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Next, my context config has

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />


<bean id="contentNegotiatingViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"
    p:order="1">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="defaultController" />
</bean>
```

Basically, I ma trying to send all requests to *.jsp to a custom error page.
I could map *.jsp also to DispatcherServlet, but, in hindsight, the problem remains the same whether I give multiple mappings to Dispatcherservlet or map to seperate Servlets like above.

Whenever, my viewResolver receives a viewName, it suffixes it with .jsp and ends up in JSPDispatcher scope again, which, in turn, forwards to a controller generating a viewName again.

So, it becomes an endless cycle of Dispatcher-Controller-ViewResolver--  forwarding to
Dispatcher-Controller- ViewResolver.....

Causing a StackOverflowError.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ha ha...wow...that's a good question of **StackOverflow** on **StackOverflow** site. ;)

Comment: Why all *.jsp requests to a custom error page ???

Comment: you need to post the code of com.dispatcher.JSPDispatcher

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the url-patterns conflict, 
The `/*` on a servlet overrides all other servlets, including all servlets provided by the servletcontainer such as the default servlet and the JSP servlet

Please have a look to the answer in below link, it might help you. I think you need to replace your `"/*"` to `"/"`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JSPDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[Url Pattern Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)