# when springmvc url-pattern should have *?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I recently studied springmvc and I confused about something，Can anyone give me some hints?

codes as follows:

```
<!-- why url pattern cannot be /* -->
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

<!--and why this can be /* -->
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: This means your application can have many endpoints .. which is not recommended. May be that's why its not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between / and /\* in servlet mapping url pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)