# web.xml URL pattern

Tags: java, html, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

Can anyone give me the information regarding rules in setting URL pattern and if I am using `/` as my index page and also I need to use `request.getRequestDispatcher("/html/file.html").forward(request,response)`.

File `file.html` is in the `html` folder which is under `war` folder, `html` folder is in the same folder of `WEB-INF`

Can any one give me suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: You need to grab a copy of the [Java Servlet Specification 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/) and read it. Chapters 10 and 12 in particular.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a servlet in your web.xml as below and then use `request.getRequestDispatcher("file").forward(request,response)`, essentially what will happen is that you would be dispatching your request to a servlet whose mapping is `/file` and that servlet would point you to your resource `/html/file.html`. Please note that even though the element name is `jsp-file` but you can point a HTML from it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/html/file.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

As an add-on - coming to how URL patterns matches the serlvet mapping present in web.xml file, below are servlet mapping rules in web.xml (sources of this are - [Servlet specs](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/) and [@BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern?rq=1)):

**1. Path mapping:**

- If you want to create a path mapping then start the mapping with `/` and end it will `/*`. For example:

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/foo/bar/*</url-pattern> <!-- http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/foo/bar/index.html would map this servlet  -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

**2. Extension mapping:**

- If you want to create an extension mapping then have servlet mapping `*.`. For example:

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> <!-- http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/index.html would map this servlet. Also, please note that this servlet mapping would also be selected even if the request is `http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/foo/index.html` unless you have another servlet mapping as `/foo/*`.  -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

**3. Default servlet mapping:**

- Suppose you want to define that if a mapping doesn't match any of the servelt mapping then it should be mapped to the default servlet then have servlet mapping as `/`. For example:

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> <!-- Suppose you have mapping defined as in above 2 example as well, and request comes for `http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/catalog/index.jsp` then it would mapped with servlet  -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

**4. Exact match mapping:**

- Suppose you want to define exact match mapping then do not use any wild card character or something, and define the exact match, like `/catalog`. For example:

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/catalog</url-pattern> <!-- Only requests with http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/catalog will match this servlet   -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

**5. Application context root mapping:**

- The empty string `""` is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
  application's context root. i.e., requests of the form `http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/`.

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern></url-pattern> <!-- Only requests with http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/ will match this servlet  Please note that if request is http://localhost:7001/MyTestingApp/abc then it will not match this mapping  -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

**6. Match all mapping:**

- If you want to match all requests to one mapping or override all other servlet mapping then create a mapping as `/*`.

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>FileServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> <!-- This will override all mappings including the default servlet mapping  -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

Below is the summary diagram from JMS specification:

[image]