# JavaEE cannot acces servlet on payara server

Tags: java, xml, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying for a couple of hours now but nothing works 
need some help here!

I'm trying to run an javaEE webapplication on `http://localhost:8080/hello-world`

When I go to http://localhost:8080 I see that the server is running. But /hello-world is not found `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`.

Project structure:

[image]

**Web.xml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.MainServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**MainServlet**:

```
package controller;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/hello-world")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("TESTTESTTEST");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why don't I see the log message: `TESTTESTTEST` in the console and why is `/test.jsp` not returned?

Please help me out.

**--EDIT**

Server configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `web.xml` you have configured your `MainServlet` to match pattern `/`.
Maybe you should use `/*` url-pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

See this Q/A for futher reading: [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Please also note that you do not access your application via `http://localhost:8080/` if you have deployed it to an arbitrary application name: if the context path is `/myWebApp`  you'll have to invoke `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/` or `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/hello-world` respectively.

In case of Apache Tomcat you can name the context path `ROOT` if you want to access it via `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/hello-world`.

**Edit:**

Seemes both mapping specifications are in conflict. Remove the Serlvet definitions from web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

In your git repo you have specified `@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/servlet")`, in `pom.xml` you name your `artifacId` "1" which yields contextpath "/1".

Now invoking `http://localhost:8080/1/` goes to `index.jsp`.
Invoking `http://localhost:8080/1/servlet` is forwarded to `test.jsp` by your method but results in error 404 as test.jsp does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I add `/*` I get `javax.servlet.ServletException: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20`. I already add the arbitrary application name so that should be good.

Comment: Does it change if you use `<url-pattern>/hello-world</url-pattern>`? Sounds like you have an infinite loop now MainServlet -> test.jsp -> MainServlet -> test.jsp ...

Comment: Then the message is gone... I've put it on Github aswel https://github.com/larsjanssen6/jea6a very weird issue :(

Comment: Still not working. The servlet `doGet` is not reached.

Comment: when I do `<url-pattern>/hello-world</url-pattern>` it's going to `index.jsp` instead of the `doGet` method of my `Servlet`.

Comment: Have updated my answer as per the findings in your GIT.

Comment: Thanks again for your time appreciate it. I've done exactly what you said but still not working. `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` I've added an image of my server configuration file. Maybe something is wrong here?

Comment: And doGet() not invoked? I'm sorry don't know much about Paraya