# What is the difference between / and /* in web.xml

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I am seeing 2 different URL pattern in web.xml. May I know what kind of URL matches with this pattern. It would be great if anyone explain this with example.

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>samplewithstar</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>samplewithoutstar</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between / and /\* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Answer (score -3):

When you give /* it will select all the html tags.