# Fail to load any resources from java EE application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a simple servlet and it works (it forward me to `about.jsp` file).

```java
@WebServlet("/about")
public class AboutServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/about.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

This `about.jsp` file needs a `navbar.css` to be displayed properly

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main</title>
        <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <header>
            About
        </header>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about" class="headerLink current-category">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/catalog" class="headerLink">Catalog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>   
 
    </body>
</html>
```

But `navber.css` loading failed.
I opened Network tab in browser and see
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/css/navbar.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 07:20:06 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Location: /about
So I have 302 redirect (I don't where this redirect) and I have content-length: 0 for my .css file. `navbar.css` located in the webapp/css/navbar.css
[image]

And the same problem also with images that places in the webapp folder.
So why I filed to load resources from server and how to make ot work?

Comment: Can you browse to  http://localhost:8080/css/navbar.css  ? Is that the correct URL? What is the name of your web app?  Maybe try using  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/navbar.css"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an issue.

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/about");
    }
}
```

This servlet redirects **all** requests from non servlet URL's to the `/about`, so when I commented it everything works OK. But I don't understand why it causes this issue and how to redirect user from `/` to `/about`

Comment: Maybe reading the answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern?rq=1 will help you